# How to print everything inside [] only?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, sed, awk

In some text files there are many `[with text inside]`. I want to print only whatever is inside the brackets. The number of brackets is the file is unknown, different for each file to parse.

I tried to parse it with `sed`, but couldn't do it.

Comment: can you add an example?

Comment: Are there more than one `[]` per line? Do they ever span multiple lines? Where is the `sed` that you tried?

Comment: More than one per line, span multiple lines. The `sed` started like  `cat file | sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/'` but it obviously doesn't work with more than one pair of brackets per line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU grep

```
grep -oP '(?<=\[)[^]]*'
```

Using a positive look-behind for the open bracket, match all non-close-bracket characters.
Example:

```
$ echo 'foo [bar] baz [hello world]' | grep -oP '(?<=\[)[^]]*'
bar
hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nE'say for /\[( [^\[\]]* )\]/xg;'
```

Or if the contents can span lines.

```
perl -0777nE'say for /\[( [^\[\]]* )\]/xg;'
```

You can pass a file name as an argument or you can use STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could try:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $1}' RS=\[ FS=\] file
```

For example

```
$ printf 'First part of foo [bar] not present, ["hello" can be\non a different\nline from "world" ] inside  brackets\n' |
awk 'NR>1{print $1}' RS=\[ FS=\]
bar
"hello" can be
on a different
line from "world"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/\[/!d;/\]/!{$!N;s/\n/ /;ba};s/[^[]*\[\([^]]*\)\]/\1\n/;P;D' file
```

N.B. it replaces newlines within a `[...]` with spaces.